# openni_camera error "bad parameter"

Tags: kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to use the openni_camera node with the command "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch". However, if I try to use any other nodes that require openni_camera (such as openni_tracker or rviz), openni_camera fails. Previously, I had a [different error that was solved](http://answers.ros.org/question/1410/openni_camera-glibc-error), but I do not know if this new error is a result of the solution or not. This is what is output.  The problem is in the last few lines.

```
robot@peoplebot2:~$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
... logging to /home/robot/.ros/log/dd0d89ac-a8ae-11e0-85d5-a088b4402bbc/roslaunch-peoplebot2-4636.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://peoplebot2:56174/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4650]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to dd0d89ac-a8ae-11e0-85d5-a088b4402bbc
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4663]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [4675]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [4676]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [4682]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [4689]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [4690]
[ INFO] [1310052981.236117554]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1310052981.236264275]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 002:07 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'B00362205337039B'
[ INFO] [1310052981.240329298]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1310052981.304115108]: [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 2:7 with serial number 'B00362205337039B'
[ INFO] [1310052981.336603405]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1310052981.341586992]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame' 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startImageStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-openni-kinect-0.2.1/debian/ros-diamondback-openni-kinect/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 158 : starting image stream failed. Reason: Bad Parameter sent to the device!
[openni_node1-2] process has died [pid 4675, exit code -6].
log files: /home/robot/.ros/log/dd0d89ac-a8ae-11e0-85d5-a088b4402bbc/openni_node1-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10609/openni_camera-error-%22bad-parameter%22/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0